# SQLite trouble with multiple concurrently open connections

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm having SQLite trouble in a multithreaded application. I have an Activity which uses a subclass of AsyncTaskLoader to perform some data import from a file (specified by an Uri as it comes from Android Storage Access Framework), and when the loader is started and does its work (it writes to the database) and the device is rotated, I get a 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)' exception. I know what the problem is (multiple SQLiteOpenHelpers accessing a database), but I am not sure how I'm supposed to fix this. Here is my code:

Activity:

```
private void importTests(Uri uri) {
    Bundle loaderArgs = new Bundle();
    loaderArgs.putParcelable(URI_IMPORTER_LOADER_ARG, uri);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, loaderArgs, this).forceLoad();
}

@Override
public Loader<Exception> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = args.getParcelable(URI_IMPORTER_LOADER_ARG);
    return new ImporterLoader(this, uri, dbHelper);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Exception> loader, Exception exception) {
    getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(loader.getId());

    if (exception != null) {
        // import failed, show toast
    } else {
        // init Ui
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Exception> loader) {
    // nothing
}
```

(Note: I don't create the Loader in onCreate; rather, I do it on demand when the import functionality is invoked, and destroy it as soon as it is ready. I'm not sure if this is a correct way of using loaders.)

Now more detailed information about the problem:

- when the activity is started, it creates a DbHelper (which is a SQLiteOpenHelper subclass), stores it in a member field, and reads the database (using getReadableDatabase(), but most likely it will be writable anyways) to initialize the Ui (show a list of items etc.)
- if an import is triggered, a Loader is created and it gets the DbHelper from the activity; this import reads a Uri using its InputStreams, does a bit of parsing and writes rows to the database
- when, during import, the device is rotated, the following happens: the loader is still going on (I don't want to destroy it, I want it to finish its task and trigger updating the Ui when it's done, possibly in the new, rotated, activity - that's the very reason I use a Loader), and it still uses its instance of DbHelper and its open connection; however, the activity is destroyed and then created again, creating another instance of DbHelper, which again tries to read the database to initialize the Ui
- as a result, there are 2 DbHelpers with one open connection each, and the second one from the new activity instance throws the SQLiteDatabaseLockedException from getReadableDatabase()

Until now, I've been using a new DbHelper in every activity in the app as it wasn't possible to use the db from multiple threads, but now that I implemented the first background use case, all hell breaks loose, of course. So actually, it seems to be possible to have multiple connections opened at the same time, as long as they are not accessed simultaneously, as I had many activities stack on top of each other, each having its own helper, and (wrongly?) didn't close them in onPause and open in onResume.

So, the question is if I'm doing anything fundamentally wrong here? Based on my research, there seems to be only 2 solutions: create a ContentProvider which will manage the database (I would like not to be forced to do this as I really don't need no CP), or somehow keep only one DbHelper/connection for the whole app. How I do it is unimportant, but as of now my favorite would probably be a singleton (yuck) initialized in a custom Application subclass. In the future I would like to try Dagger so I would probably make it a @Singleton, but not yet.

**Edit:** unfortunately, my ui still blocks - the importer transaction blocks any db reads from the ui initialization methods. I guess I need to figure out a way to start reader transactions which are not blocked by the single write tx.

**Edit 2:** I was able to successfully unblock readers while a writer is working. To do this:

- I call

  ```
  setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true);
  ```

  in the DbHelper constructor
- use

  ```
  db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  db.beginTransaction();
  ```

  in the ImporterLoader (the thing which performs the writes)

Comment: The whole point of `SQLiteDatabaseHelper` is that it should be used as a singleton. Doing that would have solved your issue as `SQLiteDatabase` uses a connection pool which only allows one connection at a time.

Comment: Well, the documentation never actually says it is supposed to be used as a singleton, but apparently this is the case as everybody keeps saying this.

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` is a helper class that opens the `SQLiteDatabase` automatically when needed, and manages the creation, upgrading, and overall handling of it in a _centralized_, _thread-safe_ manner. Having multiple instances of it for a single database defeats the whole purpose of it. In that case there is no point to using it, as you might as well handle the `SQLiteDatabase` directly.

Comment: The helper does have a few other advantages, like automatic upgrade/downgrade support, db configuration callbacks etc, which SQLiteDatabase instances don't have, so there would still be point using it. Anyways, I changed my code to use a single instance.

Comment: You only need the callbacks provided in `SQLiteOpenHelper` if you're using it as a singleton that opens the `SQLiteDatabase` _lazily_ (like it does). Otherwise you can perform it all yourself at the appropriate places with no added complexity (only adding one if/else check for the upgrade/downgrade logic).